# Correct way to use OneDrive API to sync files

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

I can't find any documentation that outlines the correct way to use OneDrive to store and keep app files synchronized across devices in C#

I have read the documentation at [OneDrive Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delta) ([archived original](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402191715/https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm)) but I don't understand the http code. (self taught C# only).

I kind of understand that I use the delta method to get changed files from OneDrive, to then save locally, but I can't figure out exactly how, so have gotten around it by checking local vs OneDrive manually using the `GetAsync<>` methods.
My current implementation (below for reference) seems to me to be rather clunky compared to what is probably handled better in the API.

In addition, it doesn't appear that there is a reverse 'delta' function? That is, where I write a file to the app locally, then tell OneDrive to sync the change. Is that because I need to actually upload it using the `PutAsync<>` method? (Currently what I am doing)

```cs
public async Task<T> ReadFromXML<T>(string gamename, string filename)
{
    string filepath = _appFolder + @"\" + gamename + @"\" + filename + ".xml";
    T objectFromXML = default(T);
    var srializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    Item oneDItem = null;
    int casenum = 0;
    //_userDrive is the IOneDriveClient
    if (_userDrive != null && _userDrive.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        try
        {
            oneDItem = await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Request().GetAsync();
            if (oneDItem != null) casenum += 1;
        }
        catch (OneDriveException)
        { }
    }
    StorageFile localfile = null;
    try
    {
        localfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filepath);
        if (localfile != null) casenum += 2;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    { }
    switch (casenum)
    {
        case 0:
            //neither exist. Throws exception to tbe caught by the calling method, which should then instantiate a new object of type <T>
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        case 1:
            //OneDrive only - should copy the stream to a new local file then return the object
            StorageFile writefile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filepath, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var newlocalstream = await writefile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                using (var oneDStream = await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.Request().GetAsync())
                {
                    oneDStream.CopyTo(newlocalstream);
                }
            }
            using (var newreadstream = await writefile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            { objectFromXML = (T)srializer.Deserialize(newreadstream); }
            break;
        case 2:
            //Local only - returns the object
            using (var existinglocalstream = await localfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            { objectFromXML = (T)srializer.Deserialize(existinglocalstream); }
            break;
        case 3:
            //Both - compares last modified. If OneDrive, replaces local data then returns the object
            var localinfo = await localfile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            var localtime = localinfo.DateModified;
            var oneDtime = (DateTimeOffset)oneDItem.FileSystemInfo.LastModifiedDateTime;
            switch (oneDtime > localtime)
            {
                case true:
                    using (var newlocalstream = await localfile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                    {
                        using (var oneDStream = await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.Request().GetAsync())
                        { oneDStream.CopyTo(newlocalstream); }
                    }
                    using (var newreadstream = await localfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                    { objectFromXML = (T)srializer.Deserialize(newreadstream); }
                    break;
                case false:
                    using (var existinglocalstream = await localfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                    { objectFromXML = (T)srializer.Deserialize(existinglocalstream); }
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return objectFromXML;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking to do.  Windows 10 has a one drive folder which you can set up to sync the files locally already.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that folder is not available on phone devices, only desktop (and possibly tablets, but I haven't got one to verify). Nonetheless, the goal is to save data to a local device, sync the file(s) back to OneDrive, so that other devices can be kept up to date (and do the same thing). The data files are too big to use `RoamingData`.

Comment: There is an c# sdk you can use if you prefer. https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp  One thing to keep in mind is that one drive can store the most recent version of the file.  If you need to doing any syncing (ie combine data from the local and one drive versions) that has to be done in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synchronization requires a few different steps, some of which the OneDrive API will help you with, some of which you'll have to do yourself.

**Change Detection**
The first stage is obviously to detect whether anything has changed. The OneDrive API provides two mechanism to detect changes in the service:

1. Changes for individual files can be detected using a standard request with an `If-None-Match`:

   ```
   await this.userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(remotePath).Content.Request(new Option[] { new HeaderOption("If-None-Match", "etag") }).GetAsync();
   ```

   If the file doesn't yet exist at all you'll get back a `404 Not Found`.
   Else if the file has not changed you'll get back a `304 Not Modified`.
   Else you'll get the current state of the file.
2. Changes for a hierarchy can be detected using the `delta` API:

   ```
   await this.userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Delta(previousDeltaToken).Request().GetAsync();
   ```

   This will return the current state for all items that changed since the last invocation of `delta`. If this is the first invocation, `previousDeltaToken` will be null and the API will return the current state for ALL items within the `AppRoot`. For each file in the response you'll need to make another round-trip to the service to get the content.

On the local side you'll need to enumerate all of the files of interest and compare the timestamps to determine if something has changed.

Obviously the previous steps require knowledge of the "last seen" state, and so your application will need to keep track of this in some form of database/data structure. I'd suggest tracking the following:

```
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Property     |                                   Why?                                    |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Local Path       | You'll need this so that you can map a local file to its service identity |
| Remote Path      | You'll need this if you plan to address the remote file by path              |
| Remote Id        | You'll need this if you plan to address the remote file by unique id         |
| Hash             | The hash representing the current state of the file                       |
| Local Timestamp  | Needed to detect local changes                                            |
| Remote Timestamp | Needed for conflict resolution                                            |
| Remote ETag      | Needed to detect remote changes                                           |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Additionally, if using the `delta` approach you'll need to store the `token` value from the `delta` response. This is item independent, so would need to be stored in some global field.

**Conflict Resolution**
If changes were detected on both sides your app will need to go through a conflict resolution process. An app that lacks an understanding of the files being synced would need to either prompt the user for manual conflict resolution, or do something like fork the file so there are now two copies. However, apps that are dealing with custom file formats should have enough knowledge to effectively merge the files without any form of user interaction. What that entails is obviously completely dependent on the file being synced.

**Apply Changes**
The final step is to push the merged state to wherever is required (e.g. if the change was local then push remote, if the change was remote then push local, otherwise if the change was in both places push both places). It's important to make sure this step occurs in such a way as to avoid replacing content that was written after the "Change Detection" step has taken place. Locally you'd probably accomplish this by locking the file during the process, however you cannot do that with the remote file. Instead you'll want to use the etag value to make sure the service only accepts the request if the state is still what you expect:

```
await this.userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(remotePath).Content.Request(new Option[] { new HeaderOption("If-Match", "etag") }).PutAsync(newContentStream);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, it looks like it is precisely the information I need to work with. I will have a go later this week and mark as answer if I can get it to work. To clarify around the `PreviousDeltaToken`, is that something that the app will need to store locally after the initial invocation, in order to compare between calls? If so, is that different to the `DeltaLink` value you mention?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my reference to `deltaLink` - it's not applicable when you're dealing with the C# SDK so I've updated that mention to `token` instead. It should be a property in the response from a `delta` call. You'll need to store that as it's how the system knows the last time you called so that it can return to you only those things that have changed.