# UWP - How to Sync files with OneDrive API in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, cloud, onedrive

I am creating a UWP application and I want to use the Onedrive API so that users can save a copy of their files in their Onedrive account, but I don't get it, so far I have only managed to login what I want is:

- upload files
- download files
- and synchronize if any of them is modified
- Create folders
- Delete Files

This code achieves the login, but I can not move beyond this, as would proceed for upload files or download them

```
 private async void btn_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.oneDriveClient == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Setting up the client here, passing in our Client Id, Return Url, 
                    // Scopes that we want permission to, and building a Web Broker to 
                    // go do our authentication. 



                    this.oneDriveClient = await OneDriveClient.GetAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient(
                        clientId,
                        returnUrl,
                        scopes,
                        webAuthenticationUi: new WebAuthenticationBrokerWebAuthenticationUi());



                   // Show in text box that we are connected.
                   txtBox_Response.Text = "We are now connected";

                    // We are either just autheticated and connected or we already connected, 
                    // either way we need the drive button now.
                    btn_GetDriveId.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                catch (OneDriveException exception)
                {
                    // Eating the authentication cancelled exceptions and resetting our client. 
                    if (!exception.IsMatch(OneDriveErrorCode.AuthenticationCancelled.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (exception.IsMatch(OneDriveErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString()))
                        {
                            txtBox_Response.Text = "Authentication failed/cancelled, disposing of the client...";

                            ((OneDriveClient)this.oneDriveClient).Dispose();
                            this.oneDriveClient = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Or we failed due to someother reason, let get that exception printed out.
                            txtBox_Response.Text = exception.Error.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((OneDriveClient)this.oneDriveClient).Dispose();
                        this.oneDriveClient = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I created a sample repository in github:[Onedrive Sync Files Sample](https://github.com/faus1000/onedriveSync)

I have already tried using Dropbox, Gdrive, but its implementation for UWP seems to be much more complex, so I chose OneDrive. any answer will be very helpful thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to Sync files with OneDrive API in C#

For using OneDrive, we suggest you implement OneDrive feature with [**OneDrive Service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive) that is part of **Windows Community Toolkit** .

**Getting Started**

To use the OneDrive API, you need to have an access token that authenticates your app to a particular set of permissions for a user. In this section, you'll learn how to:

1. Register your application to get a client ID and a client secret.
2. Sign your user in to OneDrive with the specified scopes using the token flow or code flow.
3. Sign the user out (optional).

And this is [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit//tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/OneDrive%20Service) that you could refer.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315220/correct-way-to-use-onedrive-api-to-sync-files/42474335#42474335) to understand the best way to handle the sync process once you've got a handle of the API calls themselves.